# About the local variable in Node.js promise

Tags: node.js, promise, local-variables

I am a newer of Node.js.I defined a array as a local variable,and want to use it in the following **then**,I save some useful data in it.But in the end, the array is empty.Can somebody tell me why?Thanks for your support.

```
const Device = require("./mongo.js").Device;
const Video = require("./mongo.js").Video;

Device.findOne({id:"11112222"}).exec()
  .then(function(data){
    var videoIds = data.videoIds.split(",");
    var videoId2URL = [];
    console.log(videoIds);
     videoIds.forEach(function(one){
           return Video.findOne({id:one}).exec()
            .then(function(data){
                videoId2URL.push({id:one,url:data.url});
                return videoId2URL;
            })

    });
    console.log(videoId2URL);
});
```

Comment: The main problem here is that you are mixing syncronous and asyncronous calls all together without handling properly the latter. In particolar when you are using `Promise`s you are working with asyncronous code, hence you need to change the code flow. Basically you are firing multiple Promises in the `forEach` iterator but printing (`console.log`) before they are resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are displaying `videoId2URL` too early.

`Device.findOne` returns a promise executed asynchronously. But `Video.findOne` also returns a promise executed asynchronously.

So when you do `console.log(videoId2URL);`, the promises created by `Video.findOne` are not executed yet. So your array is empty.

You must wait the end of all your promises. You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for that.

```
Promise.all(videoIds.map(function(one){
       return Video.findOne({id:one}).exec()

       .then(function(data){
            videoId2URL.push({id:one,url:data.url});
            return videoId2URL;
       });
})

.then(function() {
    console.log(videoId2URL);
});
```

Comment: why use map here instead of foreach,I tested it, when using map the code can run but using foreach it failed.Thanks.

Comment: `forEach` returns nothing. If you want to map an array into a new array, you have to use `map`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve your problem. You forEach code contains async code. Your last line does not wait for all promises to get resolved.

Try with:

```
 var arr = [];

 videoIds.forEach(function(one){
           return arr.push(Video.findOne({id:one}).exec());
    });

Promise.all(arr) // here we are waiting for all async tasks to get resolved
 .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        // parse your data here and find array of videoId2URL               
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `console.log(videoId2URL)`, you're still in the main stack for the script, while none of the `push` callbacks have been executed.

You can use an array to collect the promises returned by `Video.findOne`, and at the end use `Promise.all` to drain all the promises and do the log then.

BTW, none of the 2 `return` are necessary, you can safely remove them.
The 1st one is not used because it's in a synchronous callback for `forEach`.
The 2nd one is not used because you're relying on the side effect, rather than use the resolved value.

Try:

```js
const Device = require("./mongo.js").Device;
const Video = require("./mongo.js").Video;

Device.findOne({id:"11112222"}).exec()
  .then(function(data){
    var videoIds = data.videoIds.split(",");
    var videoId2URL = [];
    var promiseArr = [];
    console.log(videoIds);
    videoIds.forEach(function(one){
      var p = Video.findOne({id:one}).exec()
      .then(function(data){
        videoId2URL.push({id:one,url:data.url});
      });
      promiseArr.push(p);
    });

    Promise.all(promiseArr).then(function() {
      console.log(videoId2URL);
    });
});
```